# Get body name using email lib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use email lib to parse emails like this:

```
f = open('path/to/email','r')
msg = email.message_from_file(f)
print msg['From']
lmrn@mailexcite.com
```

But `msg` hasn't key Body, so what I suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
msg.get_payload()
```

to get the content of an email. Be aware that this will return a list of message objects for multipart meassages. (More [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload))